# Alternatives to QGLViewer

Tags: c++, opengl, model, 3d, preview

Is there any library similar to libQGLViewer (a ready-to-use 3d model viewer to embeed in applications) but without the Qt dependency? The application that I'm making is mostly command line, and including Qt just for model viewing looks too expensive to me...

Comment: There may be lighter weight alternatives to Qt, but you're going to be stuck with a dependency on *some* windowing system.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Coin3D: http://www.coin3d.org/

Coin is an implementation of the OpenInventor library started by SGI.  It is a C++ library with viewers, all sorts of geometric nodes, actions, events.  There are many bindings for different windowing systems.